# Covert QR code canvas to image

Tags: html5-canvas, qr-code

I need to generate QR code and display it on a voucher. And I have a print link. On click of print link I should get a print of qrcode and some other details.

But I read that canvas can't be printed using javascript print.

I need to convert the canvas to image and then display on the voucher page so that it can be printed.

Here goes the code

```
<div class="qrcode${voucher.voucherId}" style="float:left;" >
          <canvas width="100" height="100"></canvas>                        
</div>


$('.qrcode'+voucherid).qrcode({
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                text: ""+voucherid+"",
                                size: 100
                            });
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code to save the first canvas in a page to png.
Tested in Google Chrome.

```
// Save first canvas object in current document to png.

var canv = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0],
    zz = document.createElement("a");
zz.href = canv.toDataURL();
zz.setAttribute("download", "Canvas_" + (new Date).getTime() + ".png");
var myEvt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
myEvt.initEvent("click", !1, !0);
zz.dispatchEvent(myEvt);
```